# Disagreement in calculating relativistic momentum

Tags: special-relativity

I'm trying to find the relativistic momentum of an electron that has a kinetic energy of 3.0 MeV. One method I used is to equate two equations for total energy and solve for momentum.

$E_{total} = K+E_0 = \sqrt{E_0^2+(pc)^2}$

Solve for pc:

$pc = \sqrt{(K+E_0)^2-E_0^2} = \sqrt{(3.0+0.511)^2-0.511^2} \approx 3.47 MeV$

A second method is to use the kinetic energy equation in terms of momentum.

$K = \frac{p^2}{2m} = \frac{(pc)^2}{2mc^2} = \frac{(pc)^2}{2E_0} $

Solve for pc:

$pc = \sqrt{2E_0 K} = \sqrt{2*0.511*3.0} \approx 1.75 MeV$

Which one is correct, and what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

$K=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ is a non-relativistic formula, so it's not valid in this context. The other calculation is correct.